# Should I call bind before accept?

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating ServerSocket in Java:

```
ServerSocket server = null;

try {

    server = new ServerSocket(5050);

    System.out.println("Listening on port 5050");

    // Accept the client
    Socket s = server.accept();

    System.out.println("Cliented was accepted : " + s.getInetAddress() +
    "on port " + s.getLocalPort()  );

}

finally {

        if (server != null)
            server.close();
    }
```

Mostly I have just seen people using `accept` method so I am not sure about the use case of `bind` method.

But would it be better if I called `bind` before printing the message "Listening on port"?

Comment: Your title has nothing to do do with your question.

Comment: I was confused sorry, edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* calling `bind()`, implicitly, by supplying a port number to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

### Do I need to call `bind`?

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int))

> ServerSocket(int port)
>
> Creates a server socket, bound to the specified port.

So no, you don't need to call `bind` because your socket was already bound by the constructor.

### Difference `bind` / `accept`

**EDIT:** The old answer had a different title, that's why I leave this part of the answer here.

When using `bind`, you say "this server will be listening on port *XXX*". This also blocks this port for your application, so nobody else will bind on the same port then.

If you then want to *accept* a new client, you wait until some client wants to connect to the server; when the client connected, `accept` will return.

---

Please try to find solutions yourself next time by doing more research. (I'd always recommend to look at the documentation)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.